# PDF Generation SOA Architecture for Business Independence

Tags: templates, pdf-generation, soa

Currently we have a data service that is consumed by various clients inside our organization; most of them use the PDF report to view the data. The problem we are facing is that the PDF generation is obsolete and built over a technology that is becoming hard to maintain.

So what we want to achieve now is basically two goals:

1. Encapsulate all data access in a SOA manner, publishing services for RAW data, PDF report and maybe some others like "Excel RAW"
2. Give our business users the ability to load and change the templates for the PDF reports, without asking for a "development" (basically that they can be as independent as possible)

There are two main issues; the report has to be "pretty", and by that I mean that our users ask for details such as image resolution, almost pixel accuracy for text/image positioning, and that sort of stuff. The server/library that we choose has to be able to achieve this requirement.

The other is that our technology stack currently is limited to a JAVA/LINUX platform, and while we could evaluate other platforms (for instance a product developed in .NET), a solution in Java EE/LINUX would be preferable.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: The data is stored in an Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly one prickly problem you have here is providing the ability to allow your users provide "pretty"/pixel-perfect report.  Depending on what type of people your users are (technical staff / developers, business staff, general users) it may not be possible to find a system that allows you to offload significant work-effort to your users.  It is just a hard domain.

If your reports are spreadsheet style, you might wish to examine systems like **Business Objects**, **Coognos** or **Yellow Fin**.  These systems require a significant set up in terms of creating models to report against, but they can provide tools for users to design their own reports through a web interface.  These systems usually stand separate to your main application though there are certainly ways to integrate them (though for exposing services to your own customers it might be difficult to get it to work exactly as you would like).

If your reports are document-style (as opposed to spreadsheet-style), you could look at **Docmosis** which is intended for integration with applications (please note I work for the company that created Docmosis).  Docmosis allows your application to produce PDF reports from DOC/ODT/DOCX documents which act as templates for population from databases / Java objects / text etc. The templates can be provided/modified/uploaded by your users.  It integrates with Java and linux environments so your technology environment is well suited.  For many applications it provides automatically the layout based on the template that is desired.

With regards to the provision of SOA services to your users, it sound like a fine approach depending on the users you have (does a service approach provide them something easy to use?).  Because your customers are internal I'm sure you already have determined the suitability of services.

Hope that helps.